# What is the difference between app:assembleDebug vs assmbleDebug?

Tags: android, gradle, detox

As I was using **Detox** to build my project with `./gradlew assembleDebug` then I hit DEX issue because a total of 64k methods are exceeded.

If I change my code to `./gradlew app:assmebleDebug`, it builds successfully without any complaint. Would like to understand what's the major difference between these 2 commands?

I've tried looking the answer from Gradle website, doesn't find any answer though. I'm **not looking** for the difference between `assembleDebug` and `assembleRelease`

Comment: Unfortunately not, I understand difference between assembleDebug vs assembleRelease. However im looking to understand what's the difference for having `app:` behind assembleDebug. What's the difference, and what was done behind the scene?

Comment: the `app:` prefix is telling the build system to assemble only the debug version of the module called "app:". If you have more a module called "authentication" then you can only assemble its debug with `authentication:assembleDebug`

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous I see, that would basically means, if I run `./gradlew assembleDebug` it will try to compile all the modules within my project right? Otherwise I can specify which module to build. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous Thanks for answering!! Wish I could have accepted your answer.

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous how about files on the project level where all module is located including app module? Are they also being include in `app:assembleDebug`?